# Where do I get the T7-01 droid companion?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm playing as a Jedi Consular, and around level 7 I noticed that some people already have the T7-01 droid companion while I'm still all by my lonesome.  Did I miss something?  Where do I get T7-01?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The T7-01 companion is for Jedi **Knights** only. So to answer your first question, it is not possible to get a T7-01 on your Jedi **Consular**.

As to when you'll get your first companion - keep following the main story quests, and you'll get your first companion: [Qyzen Fess](http://www.torhead.com/npc/cCKwGAf). Jedi Knights temporarily get a taste of their first companion around level 5, much earlier than the other classes who only get theirs shortly before leaving their starting planet.

Answer (score 2):

@RavenDreamer is correct, the first companion for Jedi Knights is T7-01. Jedi Consulars get Qyzen Fess first. See [swtor things' Companion Overview — Jedi Consular list](http://www.hotrodacc.com/swtor/comp.html#consular) for the complete list of Consular companions.

T7-01 comes based on where you are in the class story. Jedi Knights get him on Tython, usually around level 4 to 6. They first get him after the [High-Tech Savages](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/high-tech-savages/9/) quest. Though he doesn't stay permanently until several more missions down the class quest line.